# How to capture subshell exit code when assigning subshell output to read?

Tags: bash, read

Consider:

```bash
$ read -r a <<<$(echo "foo"; exit 1)
$ echo $?
0
```

this returns 0, when I really expect a 1. How can I extract the real exit code from the subshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need multiple steps:

```bash
output=$(echo "foo"; exit 1)
status=$?
read -r a <<<"$output"       # assuming the "real" code here is more complex
```

Comment: Great, thank you Glenn